# Laravel - remember activities

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make a online quiz where user may have plenty of time for it´s fill. My question is, what is the best approach to store such a information, so users can come back after week and still will be able to see and also edit his already filled inputs.

How it can be done in Laravel ? 
Should i use session or are there any usefull packages available ?

Currently I am using DB session, but how to keep session stored in DB after user log out ?
Everytime i log out my session value is removed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Well, a session only lasts for the ... session. Store user's answers in DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new column in your answers table named "completed" this column is boolean and by default is "false".

Then when the user finalize the quiz change this value to "true".

The disadvantage of this approach is when you have required values in your answers table, you need to validate all the required values when the user finalizes the quiz by your program and not by the database structure.

Another approach is to use the methods put and get of the Laravel Cache facade like this:

```
//Use put method to store a value until $expiresAt
$expiresAt = now()->addMinutes($minutesInAWeek);
Cache::put('key', 'value', $expiresAt);

//Use the get method to retrieve the value stored
$value = Cache::get('key');
```

More of the Cache facade in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/cache)